# Stylesheets aren't loading on sub-pages

Tags: html, css

Why isn't my HTML linking my CSS properly? using the Prologue template from html5up.com... In my main directory (I mean where index.html is) I created a subfolder for the different products I want to display. This folder contains a few files: `125st.html`, `125stmain.css`, and a folder called `_notes` created by Dreamweaver. Here is the code in the 125st.html that should be linking to the 125stmain.css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="products/125st/125stmain.css" />
```

When I visit `shercousa.com/products/125st/125st.html` (It wont work for you, I've just tricked the hosts file to go to my local save instead of the live site while I work on it) it shows no CSS only the HTML. I just copied this line from the `index.html` file (which works) and changed the folder to try to direct it to the CSS clone I created. When this didn't work I tried copying and pasting the original line verbatim that works on the main site, but when linked in `125st.html` still loads no CSS at all. I'm a bit new so sorry if I'm a bit hard to follow. I can elaborate or post any more code if anyone needs to see it.

Edit: Also my images are not loading, even the ones linked in the html file.

Comment: Because the relative path is different since you're calling it from a subfolder. You will have to use the full path. When you visit shercousa.com/products/125st/125st.html, it tries to find shercousa.com/products/125st/products/125st/125stmain.css instead of shercousa.com/products/125st/125stmain.css

Answer (score 3):

If i'm not wrong, this have an easy solution.

If you're on *host/products/125st/125st.html* and you linked CSS this way:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="products/125st/125stmain.css" />
```

What it's happening there is that your file 215st.html is trying to find: *host/products/125st/125st.html/products7125st/125stmain.css*

So you can either link your css with both this ways:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/products/125st/125stmain.css" />
```

or

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="125stmain.css" />
```

I hope this works for you :)
And sorry for my english!

Comment: `host/products/125st/125st.html/products7125st/125stmain.css` should be `host/products/125st/products/125st/125stmain.css`.

Answer (score 0):

Ga, I'm such a dope. There should be a slash in front of products like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/products/125st/125stmain.css" />
```