# How do I get the name of a clicked <a> link in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have some  links on my website. Each of the links has a name. I need to get the name of the link when I click on it to use it in node. How can I get the name (or any other property) of the clicked link for using it in my node.js?

MY HTML CODE

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Наследование в CSS</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="page.css">

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <article>
    <div>
      <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="/goodsPage" class="link" name="shoes">Shoes</a></li>
        <li><a href="/goodsPage" class="link" name="jeans">Jeans</a></li>
        <li><a href="/goodsPage" class="link" name="t-shirts">T-shirts</a></li>
        <li><a href="/goodsPage">FAQ</a></li>
        <li><a href="/goodsPage">СТАТУС ЗАКАЗА</a></li>
    </div>
    </ul>
  </article>
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this? You can. use queryStrings over your URL like the following: `/goodsPage?name=shoes` and then you can capture that part on node side.

Comment: It doesn't even have to be `/goodsPage?name=shoes`. It could be `/goodsPage/shoes`, and then set up a router in your node app to take apart the URL.

Comment: I'm really sorry but I probably understood smth wrong. I'm new to all this. I did what u said. I deleted the name and added href. Then I changed my code in node.js, but when I click on the link "shoes" I get an error - "Cannot read property 'something' of undefined". 1. <li><a href="/goodsPage/shoes" class="link" >Shoes</a></li> 2. app.get('/goodsPage/:something', function (req, res) { console.log(res.params.something); Good.findOne({name: "jeans"}, function(err, foundItems){ res.render("goodsPage", {goods: foundItems}); }); })

Answer (score 2):

The [`name` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-name) is obsolete and shouldn't be used anyway. It was used to define a place to link **to**. The introduction of HTML 4 in 1998 replaced `name` on `a` elements with `id` on any element.

That said, clicks happen in the browser. Node.js, generally, is used for server-side programming. You can't tell what user is clicking on in the browser unless you change browser-side code to pass that information to the server.

Possibly what you should be doing is putting the data in the query string of the URL:

```
href="/goodsPage?something=shoes"
```

And then you can read it from the URL on the server.

If you were using Express.js then that would be a simple matter of reading the [`query` property](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query) from the request object.

But with that pattern, it looks like putting the information in the path would be better:

```
href="/goodsPage/shoes"
```

Express.js would then let you read it from the [route](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html):

```
app.get('/goodsPage/:something', function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.params.something);
  res.send(...)
})
```

Comment: I'm really sorry but I probably understood smth wrong. I'm new to all this. 
I did what u said. I deleted the name and added href. Then I changed my code in node.js, but when I click on the link "shoes" I get an error - "Cannot read property 'something' of undefined".
1. <li><a href="/goodsPage/shoes" class="link" >Shoes</a></li>
2. app.get('/goodsPage/:something', function (req, res) {
  console.log(res.params.something);
  Good.findOne({name: "jeans"}, function(err, foundItems){
    res.render("goodsPage", {goods: foundItems});
});
})

Comment: I made a typo (compare with the documentation I linked to). The params are read from the request not the response.

Comment: Thanks) it works now. But I have two more questions if it doesn't bother u too much.
1) all my css styles broke down on the page now.
2) how can i get the name of the link (i need e.g."shoes") to save into the variable

Comment: (1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37331157/stylesheets-arent-loading-on-sub-pages (2) That is what this answer explains

Comment: Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/goodsPage/page.css'

Comment: Looks like you didn't do what the question I referenced said to do.

Comment: I just don't get it) i read it 100times and I don't understand. But thank u anyway. You helped alot)

Comment: Myyyy gooood. I finally got this. Thank you, I really appreciate this)